# Mediation analysis

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mediation

for my bachelor thesis, I'm currently working on a mediation analysis.

In previous posts I have read that in mediation analysis the relationship is often classified in a diagramm like this. X is classified as the causal variable, Y is the outcome variable and M is the mediating variable. C is the total effect, c' the direct and a*b the indirect effect. In this context, it is often mentioned that the sum of the direct and indirect effect have to equal the total effect, i.e. C= c'+ a*b. What are the conclusions if this equation is not fullfilled?
My second queston is, if C is significant and c' + a*b equals C. Can I conclude then that C'+a*b is also significant or do I have to use a bootstrapped procedure to test this?
Thanks for your help!   [image: Diagramm].

Comment: If it is not that case that c' + a*b = c, then you did something wrong (or are using a nonstandard, possibly more advanced mediation model). This is an exact equivalence. Please display your results and the code you used to fit your models so we can better help you.